# strange behaviour of variables in php

Tags: php, facebook-chatbot

I am writing the chatbot for facebook using php. The query from facebook is processing through the php file. And it is simlar to that logic:

```
//got request from facebook
foreach ($data['entry'][0]['messaging'] as $message){
  if (checkAnswer($message['sender']['id'], $command)){
      $command = "";
      $command = empty($message['postback']) ? $message['message']['text'] : $message['postback']['payload'];
      $bot->send(new Message($message['sender']['id'], 'Thank you very much for participation!'));
  }
}
function checkAnswer($id, $text){
//some logic;
}
```

If two messages from different persons are sent in one moment I'm observing next. The checkAnswer function's call is not in queue (I understood it by recording the execution process with logging to file ). For example, it can be called by request 2 (request from facebook), while request 1 is not completed. And because of it (I am not sure for 100%), the variable $id is not always the same and I have the wrong algorithm execution... The logging file of start and stop is here:

```
///////start////////////////////////
01:0:21 PM ID: 250 Text: 2
///////start////////////////////////
01:0:21 PM ID: 352 Text: 1
01:0:22 PM ID: 250 Text: 2
////////stop////////////////////////
01:0:22 PM ID: 352 Text: 1
////////stop////////////////////////
```

I am working with apache2 and php7 and it is my first application with webservices. Could you give any clue how is it possible to fix it?

Comment: some update: the funciton checkAnswer during the implementation change some parameters in xml file...

Comment: Sergey, php processes can't change each other variables even if they are executed simultaneously.

Comment: That's give me direction to analyze further, thank you!

Comment: The error appears when second request wipes information of first request in xml file.... Thnx for reply @shukshin.ivan